# What is the best way to create private wikidata items

Tags: wikidata

I am looking for a way to create new private wikidata items to be integrated with the existing public wikidata.

Example:

- Fluffy (Qxxxx) is a (P31) red (Q3142) rabbit (Q9394) stuffed toy (Q682582) .
- Poo (Qyyyy) is a (P31) stuffed toy (Q682582).
- Fluffy (Qxxxx) is friends with (P3342) Poo (Qyyyy).

What would be the most straightforward way to

1. create the new items,
2. populate them with the corresponding properties, and
3. keep them in an appropriate database in such a way that they may be **queried in the same way as the public items** are?

(my main programming language is python, so suggestions of existing packages are welcome).

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing sounds like a [Wikibase](https://wikiba.se/) instance federated to Wikidata, but unfortunately, at the moment, only [properties federation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/Wikibase/master/php/md_docs_components_repo-federated-properties.html) is possible (you could reuse P31), not items federation (you would need to import Q682582 locally).

You could then use SPARQL federated queries to query both your own Wikibase instance and Wikidata.

See [Federation input](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Federation_input) for more on this topic.

Comment: This is interesting: I was not aware of it and will definitely take a look and ut sounds very promising. Thanks!